# Как загрузить дочернюю форму из DLL, созданной в другой версии Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Как можно из DLL загрузить форму в качестве MDIChild для формы вызывающего приложения?
Пробовал [такой вариант](http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/load_mdi_child_from_dll.html). Это работает, пока всё скомпилировано в одной версии Delphi.
В моём случае необходимо DLL собрать в Delphi 10.1, а основное приложение в DelphiXE. Если вместо DLL используем BPL, снова версии должны совпадать иначе всё крешится.

Пробовал ещё подключать созданную в DLL форму к основной через AttachThreadInput. Тоже работает, но из основной программы тогда не могу достучаться до созданных в DLL форм. (т.е. Handle окна мы найдём, но например FindComponent использовать не можем, т.к. это окно чужого процесса... Потому не можем менять свойства класса)

Как это правильно решить можно?

Comment: Я знал людей, которые пытались это сделать. Все они плохо кончили. Процесс у этих окон один. Типы - вот что непереносимо через границы модулей, откомпилированных в разных версиях Delphi. Максимум, чего Вы сможете достичь - это разместить одну форму в другой (не MDI), используя `TForm.CreateParented(Handle)`. Да и то - с ограниченной функциональностью.

Comment: @Igor, видимость создать получится? чтобы она размеры меняла вместе с родителем хотя бы?)

Comment: попробуйте `CreateParented`, может быть Вас это устроит. Но я настоятельно рекомендую использовать одну и ту же версию Delphi и компилировать EXE и DLL с пакетами (которые и были для этого придуманы).

Comment: @Igor, да кто же спорит) Проект большой, но старшую версию Delphi никто переходить пока не хочет, т.к. очень затратно, а новый функционалитет в старой версии не работает, думали извратиться таким образом... Ладно, поколдовать ещё попробую через WinAPI, может что придумаю. Спасибо